# How to Echo an Item after three loops in php

Tags: php

I have a scenero while i need to print an advert after every three items loop in php. I am looping like 100 video from database and after every three number of video count loop, it should echo an advert and continue, that it, echo an image in between every three items of video

like

```
<div>1<div>
<div>2<div>
<div>3<div>
ADVERT HERE
<div>4<div>
<div>5<div>
<div>6<div>
ADVERT HERE  ......... and so on
```

Below is what i have tried

```
<?php 
$qsel = "SELECT * FROM video_post ORDER BY sn DESC";

$results = mysqli_query($conn,$qsel) or die(mysqli_error());  
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($results);
$i = 0;
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    $i = $i++;
    $status = $rows['status'];
    $usern = $rows['username'];  ?>


        ///the advert
        <?php
        if($i == 3){
            print '<div class="wrapper">
                <div class="image">
                <img  src="advert/advert 4.jpg" alt="Slide 1" style="width: 65%;">
                </div>
                </div>';
            // $i=1;
        }   ?>


    <video width="320" height="240" class="embed-responsive-item" controls>
        <source src="video/<?php echo $video ; ?>" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag. 
        </video>



        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `if ($i % 3 == 0)` should do the trick

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You forgot the `$` of the variable.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: @Ezhno whoops, thanks

Comment: `$i = $i++;` can be written as `$i++;`

Comment: @NigelRen: MUST BE written `$i++;` or `$i = ++$i;`, `$i = $i++;` won't work. Or `$i = $i + 1`.

Comment: Sorry - `$i = $i++;` will run, but give the wrong result. So it must be `$i++;` in this case.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I suppose you could turn your comment into an answer. Probably answered plenty of times before, and it is pretty basic, but it is a valid Answer to this Question. Think of that sweet, sweet rep you could be farming.

Comment: @jdv naa, there was a perfectly valid answer just after I posted my comment, no need to be repetitive :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulo (%) is your friend https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

change

```
 if($i == 3){
```

to

```
 if( ($i % 3) == 0 ){
```

Comment: Nitpick: you can safely remove those parentheses. Modulo has higher precedence than comparison.

Comment: Thanks, it work, but its the loop its starting with advert, and i want advert to appear FIRST after third count only, but here it appear first

Comment: @Ademaintain `if ($i !== 0 && $i % 3 == 0)`

Comment: I agree with the nitpick, but I also wanted to make the order of operations super obvious.